# Terminology for function that has only one peak

Tags: functions, terminology

I am forgetting what the terminology to describe a function that has no local maxima but only a global maximum is. So the function, $f(x)$ monotonically increases till $x = x'$ and then monotonically decreases for $x > x'$. What is the proper mathematical terminology for describing such a function?

Comment: unimodal???????

Comment: Global extrema are also local extrema. And @Thoth is correct. +1 for him.